# How do you merge nearby regions after bwlabel in MATLAB?

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing

In MATLAB, when I apply `bwlabel` on a binary image that has objects, I get a map that identifies which pixels belong to which object.  However, there are certain objects that are close to each other that should really belong to the same object.  (e.g. Three objects labelled 1,2,3 but they should be merged as one.)  Can I merge these regions back somehow?

Comment: please post pictures, and ask more detailed.

Comment: sorry I cant uplode pics.

Comment: but if i try to make myself clearer, what attributes of regionprops can i use in order to merge few, close labels into one (close not by index but in the image)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have some code to get you started.  This is taking a sample image from MATLAB which is full of text.  After, what I did was I extracted out the bounding box of each of the letters in the text.  Once I did that, I extracted their centroid location, as well as which pixels corresponding to each object within a bounding box.  I used these two properties to help me get a rough clustering algorithm going.

Here are the steps to the algorithm I wrote:

1. Read in the image and extract each object's centroid and pixel locations for each object
2. Create an array that keeps track of which objects we need to visit
3. While there is at least one object that we need to visit:

   - Find any object that has this condition
   - Assign this object to a new cluster whose membership is just this object so far
   - Find the distance between this object's centroid to the other objects' centroids
   - If there are any centroids whose Euclidean distance is below some value, this belongs to the same cluster as the object we have declared in the beginning.  Assign all of these objects to the same cluster.
4. Repeat Step #3 until there are no more clusters we need to visit.

This is the algorithm that I wrote:

```
clear all;
close all;

%//Read in text and extract properties
BW = imread('text.png');
s  = regionprops(BW, 'Centroid', 'PixelList');

%//Create an array that tells us whether or not we have visited this
%//centroid
centroidVisited = false(length(s),1);

%//Create an array that tells us which object belongs to what cluster
membershipList = zeros(length(s),1);

%//List of all centroids for each object
centroidList = reshape([s.Centroid], 2, length(s)).';

%//Initialize cluster count
clusterNumber = 1;

%//Threshold to figure out what is near
distThreshold = 30;

%//Map that gives us which pixel belongs to which cluster
map = zeros(size(BW));

%//If there are any objects we haven't visited...
while (any(centroidVisited == false))

    %//Find one object
    ind = find(centroidVisited == false, 1);

    %//Extract its centroid
    cent = s(ind).Centroid;

    %//Grab pixels where this object is valid
    pixelLocs = s(ind).PixelList;

    %//Find Euclidean distance squared between this centroid to all the
    %//other centroids
    distCentroids = sum(bsxfun(@minus, cent, centroidList).^2, 2);

    %//Find those locations that are lower than the centroid
    %//Also ensure that we filter out those locations that we have already visited
    belowThresh = find(distCentroids < distThreshold*distThreshold & ...
                       centroidVisited == false);

    %//Mark them as visited
    centroidVisited(belowThresh) = true;

    %//Assign their membership number
    membershipList(belowThresh) = clusterNumber;

    %//For each object that belongs to this cluster, mark them with this
    %//membership number
    for k = 1 : length(belowThresh)
        placesToMark = s(belowThresh(k)).PixelList;
        map(sub2ind(size(BW), placesToMark(:,2), placesToMark(:,1))) = ...
           clusterNumber;
    end

    %//For the next cluster 
   clusterNumber = clusterNumber + 1;    
end

%//Create a colour map that is the same size as the number of clusters
colourMap = jet(clusterNumber);

%//This colour map will contain what letters belong to what cluster (colour
%//coded)
colourMapRed = colourMap(:,1);
colourMapGreen = colourMap(:,2);
colourMapBlue = colourMap(:,3);

mapColumn = map(:) + 1;
redPlane = colourMapRed(mapColumn);
greenPlane = colourMapGreen(mapColumn);
bluePlane = colourMapBlue(mapColumn);

redPlane = reshape(redPlane, size(BW,1), size(BW,2));
greenPlane = reshape(greenPlane, size(BW,1), size(BW,2));
bluePlane = reshape(bluePlane, size(BW,1), size(BW,2));

clusterMapColour = cat(3,redPlane, greenPlane, bluePlane);

figure;
subplot(1,2,1);
imshow(BW);
title('Original Image');
subplot(1,2,2);
imshow(clusterMapColour);
title('Clustered Image');
```

This is the image that I get:

[image]

The variable `clusterMapColour` will illustrate which objects belong to which cluster in a colour coded map.  What you are really after is the `map` variable.  This is pretty much like the output of `bwlabel`, except that objects with the same label `k` belong to the cluster `k`.  You will have to play around with the `distThreshold` variable to get the results that you want.  I chose `30` as something arbitrary and something to start with.  This means that anything with a `30` pixel radius of a centroid gets classified as the same membership number as that centroid.  Also, we keep track of what objects have already been visited so that they don't get reclassified again as we move along in the image.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks alot!  it's exactly the lead (and some more..) that i needed to figure out how to deal with the resultes of bwlabel. thanks

Comment: @user3684955 You're welcome! You can accept my answer if this helps. Please click on the checkmark underneath the up and down arrows at the top beside my post. Thanks :-)

Comment: @user3684955 Made a slight error in the code.  Please use the updated one that I have just made.